# Laravel queue only run one job

Tags: php, database, laravel, queue

In my table "jobs" have 5 jobs, i used the process "php artisan queue:listen" on localhost then it ran all jobs and finished. But when i used this process on server then it only once ran one jobs (same "php artisan queue:work"). I use queue_driver is "database".

Comment: post your current code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR**

`php artisan queue:work` = run one queued job and stop

`php artisan queue:listen` = run all queued jobs and listen for more until stopped

**Further detail:**

How are you running the commands? Are you just opening a terminal and running it or do you have a cron job to run at intervals?

If you're just opening a terminal and running `php artisan queue:work` will complete one task on the queue then stop, whereas if you run `php artisan queue:listen` it will process all the jobs in the queue and continue to listen for any further jobs until it is stopped.

[Read further in the docs regarding `queue:work`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#running-the-queue-listener):

> **Starting The Queue Listener**
>
> Laravel includes an Artisan command that will run new jobs as they are
>   pushed onto the queue. You may run the listener using the queue:listen
>   command:
>
> `php artisan queue:listen`
>
> **Processing The First Job On The Queue**
>
> To process only the first job on the queue, you may use the queue:work command:
>
> `php artisan queue:work`

**What you should be doing?**

I am guessing what you ideally want to do on your server is set up a cron job to run continuously at intervals and have it run `queue:work`. Better yet, acquaint yourself with the docs and make a decision after that.

See similar question answered here: [What is the difference between queue:work --daemon and queue:listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048698/what-is-the-difference-between-queuework-daemon-and-queuelisten)

Comment: Hi @haakym,
I used the command "php artisan queue:work --daemon" and succeed, this command run all jobs in my queue.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @dungdq You're welcome, glad you got it working! If the answer I gave solved your question you can mark it as correct by pressing on the tick next to my answer or if it is was helpful you can upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Xampp : `php artisan queue:listen` not listens upcoming jobs. just runs already added and stops.

Comment: Docs say otherwise: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#running-the-queue-worker you're best making your own question and explaining the whole process you're attempting and what happens and what you are expecting to happen

Comment: `queue:listen` are just processing one queue item but I have 20 queue items in the database and more getting stacked. To clear up queue items I need to run `queue:listen` again and again, each time clearing just one. @haakym

Comment: from Laravel docs
> Note that once the queue:work command has started, it will continue to run until it is manually stopped or you close your terminal

Answer (score 16):

**Update - Laravel 5.5+**

Just use:

`php artisan queue:work --once`