# SoapClient in a Laravel Job "cannot connect to host" after a while when using queue:work

Tags: php, laravel, soap, soap-client, laravel-queue

I am using a Laravel Job to schedule a Web Service call, and a single request just works fine, meaning there is no problem in connection to the host, nor any other, the web service communication is OK.

I use WSDL `SoapClient` initialization, so something like

```
$soapClient = new \SoapClient($wsdl,[
        'trace' => 1,
        'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
        'keep_alive' => true,
        'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY
]);
```

Once the queue started to get serious traffic, I enabled the queue spooling with

`php artisan queue:work --queue=soapQueue`

As expected, requests are spooled and processed, with a pretty decent speed, more or less 6 requests per second, not bad if you consider that each SOAP call takes more or less 150ms, so **900ms** for Web Service and only **100ms** for processing the queue. For each request we have an average of **16ms** for queue processing.

After a while (less than a minute) something changes: each and every web service call fails with the exception

```
[2019-03-29 09:50:29] local.ERROR: Could not connect to host  
[2019-03-29 09:50:29] local.ERROR: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://ws.host...', 'PAR_ServiceCall...', 1, 0)
```

At first I was suspecting to be hitting too hard the host, so that I was temporarily banned, but this wasn't the case: if I quit the process and restart it, it immediately starts to process messages.

Moreover, if I use `queue:listen` instead of `queue:work` (meaning that you reload the Laravel environment with each job, as explained in [What is the difference queue:work and queue:listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991251/what-is-the-difference-queuework-and-queuelisten), this does not happen, evidently caused by the reload of the environment.

Using `queue:listen` the performance degrades quite significantly, passing from 6 messages per second to 3, meaning that with the same average of 150ms needed for each call, summing up to **450ms**, the queuing process takes the remaining **550ms**, that is more or less **180ms** for each call, 11 times more than before.

It perfectly makes sense, but I was wondering if there is a way to prevent this error with `SoapClient`.

Comment: You can try to check some additional debugging info on your Soap requests ([for example, as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50847927/9348748)). But I do feel the problem is not with SoapClient but rather with Laravel.

Comment: I would also think that is a client issue but the restart queue issue is very weird, there must be something cached that clears or changes when restarting the process but honestly I have no idea what could it be.

Comment: Thanks @d3jn , I am logging the request and the response, and when the error is thrown, there is just no response (it really can't connect to host) while the request is 100% the same as before. WSDL cache works but doesn't help, meaning that if I disable it, it loads the WSDL each time. I am running the process in a docker container, I'd like to debug it but it seems a little overkill, for the moment I will not do it. Thanks for the link !

Comment: Thanks @namelivia, it's obviously some setting that is kept by the Laravel environment, the only problem is finding out which one. Restarting the queue (killing the process and re-launching a queue:work) does the trick, since it's doing manually what queue:listen does automatically, so I am not surprised about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After A LOT of attempts, I stumbled upon a solution that prevented this behavior to happen.

The problem was all about SoapClient `keep_alive` indicator.

Creating the `SoapClient` with a false `keep_alive` flag

```
$soapClient = new \SoapClient($wsdl,[
    'trace' => 1,
    'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
    'keep_alive' => false,
    'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY
]);
```

you prevent it to establish a keep-alive connection, so each call will create a brand new connection to the web service.

This may not be super optimized, but in my long-running script context prevents the weird error that I had, and testing this for a long time (hours) the error never came back