# Why this Job is not being queued and acting like a normal code?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to work a Laravel Job which must return a response immediately and execute itself in the background.

It was working fine but I don't know what went wrong because now it is not working (I just edited tried to send Notification to a user responsible for sending email updates to other users)!

I am using `sync` driver because I don't want to execute `php artisan queue:work` command every time I put something in the queue. Here is the code! In my `.env` file and `config/queue.php` file, I've set the driver to `sync`.

** I am trying to send E-mails to user which takes time **

[Click here](https://pastebin.com/vTXPkNQg) to see the code executed in **UserController**, **App\Mail\EmailUpdate** and **App\Jobs\SendEmailUpdates**.

At first (When it was working), I was being redirected back immediately! But after some time (I think 15 minutes), it is taking about 15-20 seconds to redirect me back! It is acting like a normal PHP code and sending E-mails to users before redirecting me back!

I tried resetting the code but it didn't work! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Because `sync` driver doesn't work using a background process.

Comment: So, How do you dispatch jobs with `database` driver without executing `php artisan queue:work`. And if `sync` driver doesn't work using a background process, why is it included as driver.

Comment: Actually, `sync` is available for testing on local development and on a production server you should use `queue:work --daemon` to run it as a daemon, newer version of laravel applies `queue:work` as daemon by default.

Comment: [Also check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048698/what-is-the-difference-between-queuework-daemon-and-queuelisten) and read about `supervisor` on laravel queue manual.

Comment: @TheAlpha, I checked that answer. but `queue:work --daemon` never stops the execution. What if I close terminal? It looks really really bad!

Comment: That's why you need to use a background process manager like [supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#supervisor-configuration) on the production.

Comment: I mean, It was working! with `sync`, It was returning be back in 1 second! and then It was executing rest of the code in the background! It was working smoothly! But now it's not! Are you sure `sync` does not run in background?

Comment: Okay, I got it!