# Laravel queue:work runs forever

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-queue

I have a weird issue with Laravel queue:work.
In my crontab I setup a job like described in Laravel Docs

```
* * * * * nginx php /path/to/site/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

And in my app/Console/Kernel.php I setup this:

```
$schedule->command('queue:work')->cron('* * * * *');
```

On my production server php artisan queue:work runs for a few seconds and gets "killed". Thats what I expect.

On my dev box php artisan queue:work runs forever. So activating the cron job spawns php processes until the whole memory is filled up.

Both boxes are CentOS 7.4, production runs PHP 7.1 and dev runs PHP 7.2

As said in the comment below, I don't think that the cron command is the issue.

Running form ssh:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

on dev runs forever on production a few seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between queue:work --daemon and queue:listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048698/what-is-the-difference-between-queuework-daemon-and-queuelisten)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run it once, this runs a single job and then quits the process.

`php artisan queue:work --once=1`

Or in your PHP code using the Artisan facade:

```
Artisan::call('queue:work', [
                    '--once' => 1, // Do NOT run it as a daemon (not a continuous function)
                    '--tries' => 1,
                    '--queue' => 'yourqueue',
                    '--timeout' => 0
                ]);
```