# Laravel 5.6 queue restart CPU usage

Tags: laravel, queue, cpu, laravel-5.6

I installed my Laravel 5.6 application on shared hosting service. But my hosting company is not happy with the CPU usage of my application. This high CPU usage shows up when killing the queue worker, no matter whether I kill the worker manually or via a cron job.
Can someone explain me why this 'php artisan queue:restart' takes so much CPU time? And if possible, how can I reduce?

Restart:

```
cd /home/xxxxxx/rdw_laravel/; /usr/local/bin/php72 artisan queue:restart >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Activate queue worker:

```
cd /home/xxxxxx/rdw_laravel/; /usr/local/bin/php72 artisan queue:work --daemon
```

Comment: Can you share your configurations? How are you starting the queue and how are you making sure it restarts if queue:worker process fails (ie. how are you supplementing supervisord / systemd).

Comment: I have a restart, scheduled via CRON, that starts every day at 23:55 hrs. Content of the cron command is following:
cd /home/xxxxxx/rdw_laravel/; /usr/local/bin/php72 artisan queue:restart >/dev/null 2>&1

Then, 3 minutes later the queue is started again:
cd /home/myseabou/rdw_laravel/; /usr/local/bin/php72 artisan queue:work --daemon

The objective is to have the actual version of the jobs that will be executed during the night. Via the kernel.php about 20 jobs are scheduled.

I read something about the need to clear memory, does that have effect?

Comment: Please use edit feature to edit your original post. Also include how do you start the queue workers.

Comment: Need anything more to add?

Comment: So you have only one queue worker is that correct? Also add Laravel version.

Comment: yes, only one queue, and one queue worker

Comment: What version of Laravel is this?

Comment: As the title says: 5.6 ;-)

Comment: What kind of jobs are you running in the queue? Email, image processing?

Comment: I have some groups of jobs running:
- first group to retrieve plain data (about 38.000 records) from another website. This is done in about 10 jobs
- second group to process the data that was retrieved earlier. Main thing is to translate information to other information based on tables
- third and last group is to collect information and send emails to inform members of changes in the data

Most of the processing is done by MYSQL

Comment: I added some unsets and hopefully that helps....

Comment: Indeed I see a far lower CPU usage, so this really helps

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have memory leaks so read up on [memory](https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/how-to-optimize-the-php-garbage-collector-usage-to-improve-memory-and-performance).

Straight from the documentation on how to run queue worker:

> Daemon queue workers do not "reboot" the framework before processing each job. Therefore, **you should free any heavy resources after each job completes**. For example, if you are doing image manipulation with the GD library, you should free the memory with imagedestroy when you are done.

Alternative is to use `queue:listen` instead, the difference is that `:work` boots up once and runs forever, while `:listen` boots up before each job.

> **Note**: `queue:work` and `queue:work --daemon` is equal so you do not have to run cron with the `--daemon` flag.

---

> **Note**: Why do you run `:restart` so often? I doubt that you update your code every day, so use `:restart` only when you update the code.

#### Related

[What is the difference between queue:work --daemon and queue:listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048698/what-is-the-difference-between-queuework-daemon-and-queuelisten/42895160)

Comment: Thnx for your advice!. I also saw the text you copied in, but I do not use any image. Therefor I looked for 'how to free memory like variables, objects, arrays, etc'. But until now I could not find any proper solution, at least not i the Laravel documentation. I hoped to find something there, otherwise I have to solve it in PHP on individual basis. Do you have any idea where I can find this type of solution?

Next to that, I already reduced the frequency of the restart (since I do not change in code that often anymore)