# Laravel email queue works but doesn't send

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue

I'm having a problem where i'm trying to queue a message to send to the registered user, when i am running everything works, but the queue just wont work, can someone help me with this please?
Here's the registration controller

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
      $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'type' => $data['type'],
        ]);
        $email = (string)$data['email'];
        $job = (new SendEmailJob($email))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(5));
        dispatch($job);

        return $user;
    }
```

I have checked if i can send email and it works i can send email but when i am pointing to a specific email rather to the data which came from the register form.
Here's the SendEmailJob

```
 public function handle($user)
    {
        Mail::to($user)->send(new SendEmailMailable());
    }
```

Comment: do you have a running queue? You can do this with 'php artisan queue:work' and see if that helps.

Comment: Oh wow i should have ran that? I thought the queue would just run itself

Comment: @techcyclist post that as an answer so i can select yours as the correct one

Comment: will do, glad it helped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have a queue running. You can do this with

```
php artisan queue:work
```

It's also possible you will want a failed jobs table and artisan has a command for that:

```
php artisan queue:failed-table

php artisan migrate
```

If you want to delete all your failed jobs you can do this:

```
php artisan queue:flush
```

And I recommend reading up on all this on the laravel docs site: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues

And I also want to share a [good post on stackoverflow regarding queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048698/what-is-the-difference-between-queuework-daemon-and-queuelisten).